# Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for questions about computer virus removal?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site, if any, is appropriate for questions regarding computer virus removal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com), which handles general computer hardware and software.

Answer (score 8):

As waiwai has stated, Super User is probably the best place.  To specify further, Some of the answers you may be looking for are in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware) CW question (many virus related questions on SU end up being considered duplicates of it).